# a new study shores up the popularity of unreliable studies

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "a new study shores up the popularity of unreliable studies" as "a new study confirms/supports (the idea of) the popularity of unreliable studies." Am I on the right track?

The reason is that this new study is not one of the unreliable studies that contribute to the popularity of the studies. It simply verifies the speculation that unreliable studies are more popular than solid/reliable studies.

> But the original paper has been cited 1417 times—with more than 400 of those citations coming after the 2018 replication project. That’s far more, on average, than the papers from the project that did replicate. Now, **a new study shores up the popularity of unreliable studies**: Social science papers that failed to replicate racked up 153 more citations, on average, than papers that replicated successfully.

Source: [Science](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/05/unreliable-social-science-research-gets-more-attention-solid-studies)
**Unreliable social science research gets more attention than solid studies**

Comment: ... did you think of looking up "shore up" in a dictionary? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shore-up-something. This shores up @Jack O'Flaherty's opinion about the possibly misleading interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think that's what it means. It's not put well in that sentence, because a quick reading might interpret it as meaning that the new study improves the popularity of the unreplicated studies. The title of the article makes the meaning clear.

The sentence would be clearer as
*A new study shows that unreliable studies are popular.*

Comment: ... alternatively, you could say "a new study shores up the **idea that** unreliable studies are popular"